# Thesis template to B5 paper size. What about margins?

Tags: margins, paper-size, thesis

I successfully changed the paper size from A4 to B5 of the Thesis template downloaded from http://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis

I modified the `main.tex` file by setting `twoside` and adding the following lines:

```
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[dvips=false,pdftex=false,vtex=false,b5paper]{geometry}
\geometry{bindingoffset=5mm}
\usepackage[cam,b5,center,pdftex]{crop}
```

The margins are set in the `Thesis.cls` file at line 74. The default values for A4 paper are:

```
\setmarginsrb  { 1.5in}  % left margin
               { 0.6in}  % top margin
               { 1.0in}  % right margin
               { 0.8in}  % bottom margin
               {  20pt}  % head height
               {0.25in}  % head sep
               {   9pt}  % foot height
               { 0.3in}  % foot sep
```

which have been modified to:

```
\setmarginsrb   {4.7cm} %leftmargin
                {3.4cm} %topmargin
                {3.4cm} %rightmargin
                {3.4cm} %bottommargin
                {15pt}  % head height
                {0.15in}  % head sep
                {9pt}  % foot height
                {0.3in}  % foot sep
```

These settings produced a page layout like the following.
[image: typical page layout]
The questions are:

1. What are the correct margins for the B5 paper size? My University does not provide any information.
2. With the settings I made in the `main.tex` and `Thesis.cls`, it seems I can change only left and right margin, because nothing seems to change by modifying the other parameters. Did I mess up with the code?

Comment: The `vmargin` and `geometry` packages are not compatible. Moreover, `vmargin` is not compatible with `crop`, as far as I know.

Comment: And the version of the template you are using is very very obslete. I suggest to get the recent version.

Comment: The question what margins are correct, depends on many things. For the SE network, that particular question is off-topic, opinion based *and* too broad.

Comment: @Johannes_B should I remove the first question?

Comment: No. The template as it was, was bad. Still, i think templates are bad. Upgrading to the new version will get you further and remove the issues you have; i hope. Do your stuff. The rest will resolve itselve.

Comment: I'm getting some results with the new version of the template, which was unavailable in August, when I have started this work. For the margins to choose, I'm following a rule of thumbs found on the internet. To mark the question as "closed", do I need someone to answer it or not?

Comment: Why do you load package `crop`?

Comment: I followed an example found on the GuIT (italian) forum to get the B5 paper size from A4 and tried to adapt it to my case. As you said before, the package I was using is obsolete. The margins parameters were loaded in the `Thesis.cls` file, so I messed up with the `geometry` and `crop` packages. The obtained paper size was right (176x250 mm), but I could not change the margins easily. The newest version is much simpler and all I need is to change the paper size and margins in `geometry`, which is loaded by default in the `main.tex`. Thus, my issue is solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved my issue by upgrading the template to the latest version, which includes the specification of the margins in the `main.tex` file.

```
\geometry{
    paper=b5paper,
    inner=16mm,         % Inner margin
    outer=24mm,         % Outer margin
    bindingoffset=10mm, % Binding offset
    top=20mm,           % Top margin
    bottom=28mm,        % Bottom margin
    %showframe,         % show how the type block is set on the page
}
```

The class file, that now is named `MastersDoctoralThesis.cls`, includes the following code, which **I did not change**.

```
\RequirePackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    headheight=4ex,
    includehead,
    includefoot
}

\raggedbottom
```

Finally, I have found some rules of thumb about margins to use [here](http://www.unife.it/letterefilosofia/comunicazione/insegnamenti/laboratorio_grafica/materiale_didattico/grafica-editoriale/view) (in Italian).

Comment: Glad to hear that you could resolve your issues and *hopefully* a better experience with the upgraded version.