# Adapt harvard-thesis template to B5 format

Tags: formatting, paper-size, transformation

I have no really idea how to adapt the harvard-thesis template to B5 format. I found this post related with, but I don't know how to adapt it to my template:

[Thesis template to B5 paper size. What about margins?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/284455/thesis-template-to-b5-paper-size-what-about-margins)

My University doesn't clarify the margins and other metrics.

Heres is a copy of the template I am using:

https://es.sharelatex.com/project/58455964c0ba0b593dc919de

Comment: The link you've provided just points to a driver file that loads the `harvard-thesis` document class. What you need to do is to create a copy of `harvard-thesis.cls` and to modify the copy suitably. Is `havard-thesis.cls` available online somewhere?

Comment: The link provided is a copy and you can modify suitably. The `hardvar-thesis.cls`is hosted [here] (https://es.sharelatex.com/templates/thesis/harvard-phd). I'm working over sharelatex.

Comment: The link only works if one is registered with sharelatex.com -- something I'm not inclined to do. Is there any way to access the files *without* being registered with sharelatex.com?

Comment: Link should works without registration

Comment: if you download the archive from the github account and open the `Dissertate.cls` file, you can see on line 14 `\LoadClass[12pt, oneside, letterpaper]{book}`. Change it into `\LoadClass[12pt, oneside, b5paper]{book}`, and also `\RequirePackage[width=5.75in, letterpaper]{geometry}` into `\RequirePackage[width=5.75in, b5paper]{geometry}`. However, since you changed the `.cls` file, you should save it under another name in order to avoid later confusion...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open the [GitHub repo of the `Dissertate` class](https://github.com/suchow/Dissertate), and download the [Harvard `.zip` file](https://s3.amazonaws.com/dissertate.io/Dissertate-Harvard-LaTeX.zip), you can find the `Dissertate.cls` file that defines the class you want to use.

In this class definition, you can observe that it loads `letterpaper` option by default (see e.g. line 14).
The solution is thus to **create a new class based on `Dissertate.cls`, but that loads the `b5paper` option instead of `letterpaper`**.

Caution: when you modify one class, you should create a copy of it and rename it, since it's not the same class anymore. See below an example that you can save as **`DissertateB5.cls`**. Following items have been changed:

- Header: Filename, date of last update, etc.
- `\ProvidesClass`:  updated with the new name
- `\LoadClass` : changed in order to load the `book` class with the `b5paper` option
- `\RequirePackage[<...>]{geometry}` : load with the `b5paper` option, instead of `letterpaper`

Thus,

1. copy-paste this text into a file named `DissertateB5.cls` and saved in the same directory as your `.tex` document.
2. In your `.tex` documents, use `\documentclass{DissertateB5}` where you used `\documentclass{Dissertate}`

That's all !

---

```
% -------------------------------------------------------------------
%  @LaTeX-class-file{
%     filename        = "DissertateB5.cls",
%     version         = "2.0",
%     date            = "06 December 2016",
%     codetable       = "ISO/ASCII",
%     keywords        = "LaTeX, Dissertate",
%     supported       = "Send email to suchow@post.harvard.edu.",
%     docstring       = "Class for a dissertation."
% --------------------------------------------------------------------

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{DissertateB5}[2016/12/06 v2.1 DissertateB5 Class]
\LoadClass[12pt, oneside, b5paper]{book}

%
% Options
%
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}

% Line spacing: dsingle/ddouble
%   Whether to use single- or doublespacing.
\newtoggle{DissertateSingleSpace}
\togglefalse{DissertateSingleSpace}
\DeclareOption{dsingle}{
    \toggletrue{DissertateSingleSpace}
    \ClassWarning{Dissertate}{Single-spaced mode on.}
}
\DeclareOption{ddouble}{\togglefalse{DissertateSingleSpace}}

\ProcessOptions\relax

% Line Spacing
%   Define two line spacings: one for the body, and one that is more compressed.
\iftoggle{DissertateSingleSpace}{
    \newcommand{\dnormalspacing}{1.2}
    \newcommand{\dcompressedspacing}{1.0}
}{
    \newcommand{\dnormalspacing}{2.0}
    \newcommand{\dcompressedspacing}{1.2}
}

% Block quote with compressed spacing
\let\oldquote\quote
\let\endoldquote\endquote
\renewenvironment{quote}
    {\begin{spacing}{\dcompressedspacing}\oldquote}
    {\endoldquote\end{spacing}}

% Itemize with compressed spacing
\let\olditemize\itemize
\let\endolditemize\enditemize
\renewenvironment{itemize}
    {\begin{spacing}{\dcompressedspacing}\olditemize}
    {\endolditemize\end{spacing}}

% Enumerate with compressed spacing
\let\oldenumerate\enumerate
\let\endoldenumerate\endenumerate
\renewenvironment{enumerate}
    {\begin{spacing}{\dcompressedspacing}\oldenumerate}
    {\endoldenumerate\end{spacing}}

% Text layout.
\RequirePackage[width=5.75in, b5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\RaggedRight
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\parindent 12pt
\RequirePackage{lettrine}
\RequirePackage{setspace}
\RequirePackage{verbatim}

% Fonts.
\RequirePackage{color}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\RequirePackage{url}
\RequirePackage{amssymb}
\RequirePackage{mathspec}
\setmathsfont(Digits,Latin,Greek)[Numbers={Proportional}]{EB Garamond}
\setmathrm{EB Garamond}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\addfontfeature{RawFeature=+tnum}}
\widowpenalty=300
\clubpenalty=300
\setromanfont[Numbers=OldStyle, Ligatures={Common, TeX}, Scale=1.0]{EB Garamond}
\newfontfamily{\smallcaps}[RawFeature={+c2sc,+scmp}]{EB Garamond}
\setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase, BoldFont={Lato Bold}]{Lato Regular}
\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Source Code Pro}
\RequirePackage[labelfont={bf,sf,footnotesize,singlespacing},
                textfont={sf,footnotesize,singlespacing},
                justification={justified,RaggedRight},
                singlelinecheck=false,
                margin=0pt,
                figurewithin=chapter,
                tablewithin=chapter]{caption}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
\RequirePackage{microtype}


% Headings and headers.
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\RequirePackage[tiny, md, sc]{titlesec}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\pagestyle{plain}
\RequirePackage{titling}

% Front matter.
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalsize \scshape}
\renewcommand\listfigurename{Listing of figures}
\renewcommand\listtablename{Listing of tables}

% Endmatter
\renewcommand{\setthesection}{\arabic{chapter}.A\arabic{section}}

% References.
\renewcommand\bibname{References}
\RequirePackage[super,comma,numbers]{natbib}
\renewcommand{\bibnumfmt}[1]{[#1]}
\RequirePackage[palatino]{quotchap}
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace*{-0.5\baselineskip}}
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadendvskip}{\vspace{1.3\baselineskip}}

% An environment for paragraph-style section.
\providecommand\newthought[1]{%
   \addvspace{1.0\baselineskip plus 0.5ex minus 0.2ex}%
   \noindent\textsc{#1}%
}

% Align reference numbers so that they do not cause an indent.
\newlength\mybibindent
\setlength\mybibindent{0pt}
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
    {\chapter*{\bibname}%
     \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\bibname}{\MakeUppercase\bibname}%
     \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}
          {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{999}}
           \leftmargin\labelwidth
            \advance\leftmargin\dimexpr\labelsep+\mybibindent\relax\itemindent-\mybibindent
           \@openbib@code
           \usecounter{enumiv}
           \let\p@enumiv\@empty
           \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}
     \sloppy
     \clubpenalty4000
     \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
     \widowpenalty4000%
     \sfcode`\.\@m}
    {\def\@noitemerr
      {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}
     \endlist}

% Some definitions.
\def\advisor#1{\gdef\@advisor{#1}}
\def\coadvisorOne#1{\gdef\@coadvisorOne{#1}}
\def\coadvisorTwo#1{\gdef\@coadvisorTwo{#1}}
\def\committeeInternal#1{\gdef\@committeeInternal{#1}}
\def\committeeInternalOne#1{\gdef\@committeeInternalOne{#1}}
\def\committeeInternalTwo#1{\gdef\@committeeInternalTwo{#1}}
\def\committeeExternal#1{\gdef\@committeeExternal{#1}}
\def\degreeyear#1{\gdef\@degreeyear{#1}}
\def\degreemonth#1{\gdef\@degreemonth{#1}}
\def\degreeterm#1{\gdef\@degreeterm{#1}}
\def\degree#1{\gdef\@degree{#1}}
\def\department#1{\gdef\@department{#1}}
\def\field#1{\gdef\@field{#1}}
\def\university#1{\gdef\@university{#1}}
\def\universitycity#1{\gdef\@universitycity{#1}}
\def\universitystate#1{\gdef\@universitystate{#1}}
\def\programname#1{\gdef\@programname{#1}}
\def\pdOneName#1{\gdef\@pdOneName{#1}}
\def\pdOneSchool#1{\gdef\@pdOneSchool{#1}}
\def\pdOneYear#1{\gdef\@pdOneYear{#1}}
\def\pdTwoName#1{\gdef\@pdTwoName{#1}}
\def\pdTwoSchool#1{\gdef\@pdTwoSchool{#1}}
\def\pdTwoYear#1{\gdef\@pdTwoYear{#1}}
% School name and location
\university{Harvard University}
\universitycity{Cambridge}
\universitystate{Massachusetts}

% School color found from university's graphic identity site:
% http://isites.harvard.edu/icb/icb.do?keyword=k75408&pageid=icb.page392732
\definecolor{SchoolColor}{rgb}{0.6471, 0.1098, 0.1882} % Crimson
\definecolor{chaptergrey}{rgb}{0.6471, 0.1098, 0.1882} % for chapter numbers

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=SchoolColor,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=SchoolColor,
}

% Formatting guidelines found in:
% http://www.gsas.harvard.edu/publications/form_of_the_phd_dissertation.php
\renewcommand{\frontmatter}{
    \input{frontmatter/personalize}
    \maketitle
    \copyrightpage
    \abstractpage
    \contentspage
    % \listoffigures % optional
    \dedicationpage
    \acknowledgments
}

\renewcommand{\maketitle}{
    \pagenumbering{roman}
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \vspace{100pt}
    \begin{center}
    \Huge \textcolor{SchoolColor}{\thetitle} \normalsize \\
    \vspace{100pt}
    \textsc{a dissertation presented \\ by\\
    \theauthor\\ to\\ The Department of \@department\\
    \vspace{12pt}
    in partial fulfillment of the requirements\\
    for the degree of\\ \@degree\\
    in the subject of\\ \@field\\
    \vspace{12pt}
    \@university\\ \@universitycity, \@universitystate\\
    \@degreemonth\ \@degreeyear}
    \end{center} \vspace*{\fill}
}

\newcommand{\copyrightpage}{
    \newpage
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \scshape \noindent \small \copyright \small 2014\hspace{3pt}-- \theauthor \\
    \noindent all rights reserved.
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \newpage
    \rm
}

\newcommand{\abstractpage}{
    \pdfbookmark{Abstract}{Abstract}
    \newpage
    \pagenumbering{roman}
    \setcounter{page}{3}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \lhead{Thesis advisor: Professor \@advisor} \rhead{\@author}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}
    \vspace*{35pt}
    \begin{center}
        \Large \textcolor{SchoolColor}{\@title} \normalsize \\
        \vspace*{20pt}
        \scshape Abstract \\ \rm
    \end{center}
    \begin{spacing}{\dnormalspacing}
        \input{frontmatter/abstract}
    \end{spacing}
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \newpage \lhead{} \rhead{}
    \cfoot{\thepage}
}

\newcommand{\contentspage}{
    \pdfbookmark{\contentsname}{Contents}
    \tableofcontents
}

\newcommand{\dedicationpage}{
    \cleardoublepage
    \phantomsection
    \pdfbookmark{Dedication}{Dedication}
    \newpage \thispagestyle{fancy} \vspace*{\fill}
    \scshape \noindent \input{frontmatter/dedication}
    \vspace*{\fill} \newpage \rm
    \cleardoublepage
}

\newcommand{\acknowledgments}{
    \chapter*{Acknowledgments}
    \noindent
    \begin{spacing}{\dnormalspacing}
        \input{frontmatter/thanks}
    \end{spacing}
    \vspace*{\fill} \newpage
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
}


\renewcommand{\backmatter}{
    \begin{appendices}
        \include{chapters/appendixA}
    \end{appendices}
    \input{endmatter/personalize}
    \clearpage
    \begin{spacing}{\dcompressedspacing}
        \bibliography{references}
        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}
        \bibliographystyle{apalike2}
        \include{endmatter/colophon}
    \end{spacing}
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works really fine. Just only one comment: margins, with 5.75 inches, are really those? Would be better to see 3cm for left and right margins. Should I change inches widht?

Comment: yes you can! Either you define your own value, or you use length specified in [the answer you already mentioned] (http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/285334/64454).